# Facebook how to get a friends_hometown?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using FB graph v3 and i already ask for permission to friends data. But when i try to get access it won't return any value for hometown

my permission array
'scope'         => 'offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_location,user_about_me,user_hometown, friends_hometown, friends_location'

if ($user){
        //get user basic description
        $userInfo           = $facebook->api("/$user");
        //print_r($userInfo);
        try{

```
        $friends =  $facebook->api("/$user/friends");
    //  echo $friends->('friends_hometown');
        print_r($friends->data);


    }
```

Returned is:
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Jim Wel [id] => 100001572804563 ) )

How can i get friends_hometown friends_location???

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly how the Facebook SDK works since I wrote my own, but id it returns the JSON properly this should work:

```
 $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');
 for($i = 0; $i < count($friends); $i++){
      $friend = $facebook->api('/'.$friends[$i]->id);
      echo $friend->hometown->name.'<br />';
 }
```

Comment: ,i had to rewrite it a bit to get the id $friend = $facebook->api('/'.$friends->data[0]->id); and i came up with my own solution but that one was way too complex. Using the id and making a $fql query.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to request permissions "friends_hometown" too.